# Is it OK to use the addresses of std::vector elements as pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, stdvector

Consider the situation where there is some `std::vector<ClassA>` and then there are objects of another class that contain pointers to elements of this vector, e.g.:

```
ClassB Object(&ClassA[12]);
```

Is this a mine field, in case the vector gets resized, etc.? Should I have an `std::vector<ClassA *>` instead?

Comment: Indeed, references to vector elements are generally invalidated when you mutate the vector.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks. Am I correct that a vector of pointers would be the way forward here?

Comment: @mga I would consider rewriting `ClassB`. Raw pointers are never really a good idea.

Comment: @mga: use a [boost::stable_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.stable_vector), or if you refuse to use boost, then `std::list<T>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`, yes.

Comment: @mga A vector of pointers does alleviate your immediate concern of the memory address of the objects not changing, but it just opens up another can of worms where you must be careful to delete every element in the vector before removing them (assuming they're dynamically allocated). A better solution might be `vector<unique_ptr<ClassA>>`, or even `list<ClassA>`.

Comment: @mga: Probably not. There's probably a better solution. Don't use pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `vector` is resized (e.g. if a `push_back()` exceeeds vector's current capacity, so there is a need to allocate a bigger chunk of heap memory), then the addresses of vector elements change (so, extern pointers to vector's elements are invalidated).

If you store *pointers* to `ClassA` inside the vector, instead of direct instances of `ClassA`, then the pointers are still valid after vector resize.

However, note that storing *owning raw pointers* in a `std::vector` is a very bad thing, and source of leaks.
You should store *owning* **smart pointers**, e.g. `std::unique_ptr` (for unique ownership semantics) or `std::shared_ptr` (for shared ownership semantics).

For example, you can have a `vector<unique_ptr<ClassA>>` (so, the vector *owns* the dynamically allocated instances of `ClassA`), and you can have *raw* **observing** pointers (e.g. simple `ClassA*`) from an external object.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe, as long as you are not storing that address for later usage (where something that causes the vector to resize or otherwise move the memory would leave you with a dangling pointer).

If you intend to hold onto that pointer, it would be better to have a vector of pointers (or a vector of smart pointers) instead:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ClassA>> myVector;
```